# python3.6 - can't install modules '_sqlite3' & '_bz2'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, fedora, bzip2

I'm using a Fedora distribution and working with python 3.6.

While importing both `nltk` and `sklearn` it says I'm missing said 2 modules (respectively). I tried fixing it by first downloading these modules using:
`sudo yum install sqlite-devel` and
`sudo yum install bzip2-devel` but got the following errors (respectively)

```
Error downloading packages:
  sqlite-devel-3.7.17-8.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Error downloading packages:
  bzip2-devel-1.0.6-13.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What exactly do I need to do in order to install these modules? I tried sniffing around Google and SO but couldn't find a resolution that worked for me.

Please help!

Edit: I understand that I need to re-compile python after installing said packages (not that I know how to re-compile it) but I can't even download these packages.

Comment: Use [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) and solve your problems. :-)

Comment: @Sidon never heard of it, I have installed it now but how do I use it to solve my problem? thanks.

Comment: @Sidon it seems that it took care of bzip2 but not sqlite3

Comment: Anaconda isolate python envs so efficiently that you do not have to install or to change things in your distro.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried:

> sudo dnf install bzip2

To install basic SQLite (if it is not already), simply type:

> sudo dnf install sqlite or sudo yum install libsqlite3-dev

This package provides the basic library and the command-line client sqlite. In order to access SQLite databases from various programming languages (C, Tcl, Java), the language bindings need to be installed separately:

> sudo dnf install sqlite-devel sqlite-tcl sqlite-jdbc

Comment: I wish... I can't even `yum install dnf`.. these are the errors it shows:  http://imgur.com/kEEfU4v (too long for comment)

Comment: are u using sudo or just yum install?

Comment: which fedora version you are using?

Comment: Via `cat /etc/redhat-release` command: `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)`

Comment: I tried running your command (assuming the second 'install' was a typo) and got this: `No package libsqlite3-dev available.`

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I did eventually is installing anaconda as @Sidon suggested (in /usr/lib/anaconda3) and changed the symbolinc of python3 (`ln -s /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python3`) and it seems it worked.

Comment: It is not necessary with conda. See [my answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44699909/2879341)

Answer (score 0):

### Anaconda different envs:

With anaconda you can install different envs and then change according to your necessity, for example:

**Install python 2.7**

```
conda-env create -n py27 python=2.7
```

**Install python 3.6**

```
conda-env create -n p36 python=3.6
```

**List environments installed**

```
conda-env list
```

Output (my case):

```
autopart                 /home/sidon/anaconda3/envs/autopart
eztables                 /home/sidon/anaconda3/envs/eztables
gestauto                 /home/sidon/anaconda3/envs/gestauto
llabs                    /home/sidon/anaconda3/envs/llabs
material                 /home/sidon/anaconda3/envs/material
olist                    /home/sidon/anaconda3/envs/olist
py27                     /home/sidon/anaconda3/envs/py27
scrum                    /home/sidon/anaconda3/envs/scrum
root                  *  /home/sidon/anaconda3
```

**Change environment:**

```
sidon@sidon-pc-linux:~$ source activate py27 <enter>
(py27) sidon@sidon-pc-linux:~$
```

**Installing scikit on py27**

```
$ source activate py27 <enter>
$ (py27) pip install scikit-learn  

or (if fail)
$ (py27) conda install scikit-learn
```